# Reproduce a html5 video streaming from a specific time

Tags: html, video-streaming

Hello I have to reproduce an html5 video streaming from an specific time and the browser does not do it. I have tried these options and none of them are useful. For example:

```
 <video width="1800" height="1000" id="video1" data-tooltip="pelea Ertzainza" controls="">
        <source src="......./5c949390643553f7c6c92dcd" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
```

That was a type of streaming video to transmit.
I have tried the following options:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 50;

}, false);/script>
```

I have also tried this option:video>

```
<video> 
   <source src="......./5c949390643553f7c6c92dcdt=10,20" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Any idea ??
Thanks
Gorka

Answer (score 0):

You can use media fragments in the source URL, but you're doing it wrong in your code:

```
<source src="......./5c949390643553f7c6c92dcdt=10,20" type="video/mp4">
```

You must have a `#` between the rest of the URL, and the fragments indicating time.

```
<source src="......./5c949390643553f7c6c92dcd#t=10,20" type="video/mp4">
```